# Joomla Loadmodule plugin

Tags: joomla

With Joomla, I'm using LoadModule plugin to inlude a auhentication module into an article, like this: {loadposition user10}. So, I have created an authentication module in position user10. Its working, but not as I would like.

I set LoadModule plugin to "Wrapped by divs". However, the authentication form is not wrapped by anything. Starts with  and ends with . Plus... a normal menu that points to authentication page, wrapps form fields in a diferent way...

I have to style this form in a different way, and even Module Class Sufix, in this authentication module that I've created, is not working...

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Escar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either wrap the code in a container in the article (switch to HTML mode) i.e.

```
<div id="myWhatever">{loadposition xxx}</div>
```

Or you can create a template override for the module and add your markup there.

```
/templates/my_template/html/mod_whatever/default.php
```